# Compute F statistics iteratively from data.frame, with a specific column having the categories to be compared

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an oversimplified data.frame that looks like this (the real data.frame has > 10 classes in the "Class" column and > 1000 rows):

```
Bin    Class       Var      n
0.1    benign      0.04     15
0.1    damaging    0.3      14
0.1    all         0.0006   16
0.2    benign      0.1      13
0.2    damaging    0.04     16
0.2    all         0.03     10
0.3    benign      0.07     8
0.3    damaging    0.06     12
0.3    all         0.1      10
```

For every value in "Bin", I would like to compute F statistics between "all", "benign" and "damaging" ("Class" column), using the corresponding variances ("Var" column) and sample sizes ("n" column). As output I would get, for "all vs benign" and "all vs damaging" comparisons, an observed F statistic (Obs_F), an expected F statistic (Exp_F), and a p-value.

Example for all vs benign, Bin "0.1", with corresponding formulas:

```
Obs_F = 0.04/0.0006 # higher Var/lower Var
Exp_F = qf(.95, df1= 15 , df2 = 16) # df1 and df2 = "n" of higher and lower Var, respectively
p-value = pf(Obs_F, df1= 15 , df2 = 16 ) # df1 and df2 = "n" of higher and lower Var, respectively

# I suspect using ifelse() function is a good way of sorting the highest vs lower Var and degrees of freedom (df1 and df2).
```

I expect to get an output data.frame that looks like this:

```
Bin  Comparison        Obs_F    Exp_F   p-value
0.1  all_vs_benign      …        …        …
0.1  all_vs_damaging    …        …        …
0.2  all_vs_benign      …        …        …
0.2  all_vs_damaging    …        …        …
0.3  all_vs_benign      …        …        …
0.3  all_vs_damaging    …        …        …
```

I have tried with dplyr, aggregate, and similar functions, but so far I only manage to calculate F stats 1 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R, using `Map` and `mapply`. First we need to create a function to return your desired results. We split the original data frame on `Class` and create a second function (`fun2`) to `Map` the first `fun1` to that list. Then the next step is to create a matrix with all combinations of interest. Finally, use `mapply` to apply the function to the matrix.

```
fun1 <- function(d1, d2){
  Obs_F <- pmax(d1$Var, d2$Var)/pmin(d1$Var, d2$Var)
  dd <- rbind(d1, d2)
  n_min <- dd$n[dd$Var == pmin(d1$Var, d2$Var)]
  n_max <- dd$n[dd$Var == pmax(d1$Var, d2$Var)]
  Exp_F <- qf(.95, df1= n_min, df2 = n_max)
  p_value <- pf(Obs_F, df1= n_min, df2 = n_max)
  return(data.frame(Obs_F, Exp_F, p_value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

l1 <- split(df, df$Class)
fun2 <- function(x, y){ Map(fun1, l1[x], l1[y])}

m1 <- combn(1:length(l1), 2)[,1:length(l1)-1] 

final_list <- mapply(fun2, m1[1,], m1[2,])

#tidy up to required data frame
final_df <- do.call(rbind, c(final_list, make.row.names = FALSE))
final_df$Bin <- rep(unique(df$Bin), 2) 
final_df <- final_df[order(final_df$Bin),]
final_df$Comparison <- rep(c('all_vs_benign', 'all_vs_damaging'), length(unique(df$Bin)))

final_df
#       Obs_F    Exp_F   p_value Bin      Comparison
#1  66.666667 2.352223 1.0000000 0.1   all_vs_benign
#4 500.000000 2.373318 1.0000000 0.1 all_vs_damaging
#2   3.333333 2.671024 0.9772730 0.2   all_vs_benign
#5   1.333333 2.493513 0.7067062 0.2 all_vs_damaging
#3   1.428571 3.071658 0.7068978 0.3   all_vs_benign
#6   1.666667 2.753387 0.8009820 0.3 all_vs_damaging
```

Answer (score 2):

It is often helpful to start with a helper function so you aren't tangling up what you want to do with how to apply it to your data arrangement.

```
mytest <- function(vx,nx,vy,ny) 
    if(vx < vy) {
        mytest(vy,ny,vx,nx) 
    } else {
        Obs_F=vx/vy
        Exp_F = qf(.95,df1=nx,df2=ny)
        p.value=pf(Obs_F,df1=nx,df2=ny)       
        list(Obs_F=Obs_F,Exp_F=Exp_F,p.value=p.value)}
    }
}
```

Then, consider rearranging your data to have the comparison data on the same row.

```
m <- merge(df[df$Class!="all",],df[df$Class=="all",],by="Bin")
```

With these preliminaries out of the way the solution is fairly easy

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(m), function(r) with(m[r,],
    c(Bin,
      Comparison=paste(Class.x,Class.y,sep="_vs_"),
      mytest(Var.x,n.x,Var.y,n.y)))))
```

Note, I'm not sure what your setup is, but:

- If the "all" class includes the others, you need to think about how you are violating assumptions of independence in the F-test.
- If you are trying to do a two sided test, you need to adjust your "alpha" and consider both sides in the p-value.

Comment: If you have the upstream data, not just the summary statistics, see also `var.test`.

Comment: Thanks very much @A. Webb !. Even though your solution is even more simple than Sotos'es, he posted the solution first. I also appreciate your last comments very much.

Comment: @Lucas I suggest you develop a comprehensive set of test cases where you compare hand verified results to selected code.

Comment: Hi @A. Webb, I just posted a similar question (link below), were I would like to compare single "classes" along all bins, performing all possible combinations. It would be really great to have your feedback, as I am using the solution you created and I don't have enough knowledge to find a solution. Thanks very very much in advance. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446365/compute-f-statistics-iteratively-from-data-frame-comparing-all-possible-combina

Answer (score 1):

There are surely better ways, but as seeing no one is answering this is my attempt at tackling this problem with `dplyr`:

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Bin) %>% 
  filter(Class != 'damaging') %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(Var),
         comparison = 'all_vs_benign') %>% 
  unite(temp, Var, n) %>% 
  select(-Class) %>% 
  spread(rank, temp, sep = '_') %>% 
  separate(rank_1, into =c('VarMin', 'nMin'), sep ='_') %>% 
  separate(rank_2, into =c('VarMax', 'nMax'), sep = '_') %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-Bin, -comparison), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(Obs_F = VarMax / VarMin,
         Exp_F = qf(.95, df1 = nMax, df2 = nMin),
         pValue =pf(Obs_F, df1 = nMax, df2 = nMin)) %>% 
  select(-matches('.Min|Max')) -> benign


mydf %>% 
  group_by(Bin) %>% 
  filter(Class != 'benign') %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(Var),
         comparison = 'all_vs_damaging') %>% 
  unite(temp, Var, n) %>% 
  select(-Class) %>% 
  spread(rank, temp, sep = '_') %>% 
  separate(rank_1, into =c('VarMin', 'nMin'), sep ='_') %>% 
  separate(rank_2, into =c('VarMax', 'nMax'), sep = '_') %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-Bin, -comparison), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(Obs_F = VarMax / VarMin,
         Exp_F = qf(.95, df1 = nMax, df2 = nMin),
         pValue =pf(Obs_F, df1 = nMax, df2 = nMin)) %>% 
  select(-matches('.Min|Max')) -> damaging

bind_rows(benign, damaging) %>%
  arrange(Bin, comparison) %>%
  as.data.frame -> result
```

The manipulation is carried separately for the two group, and then `row_binded`. The difficulty lies in selecting the `n` for the degrees of freedom, based on the `Var`.
The only way I found is to:

1. Find the max and min `Var` via the `min_rank`
2. Unite the numerical columns (ugly, but gets the job done)
3. Spread the ranks into columns
4. Separate the numerical columns and transform back as numerical
5. Calculate the result of interest

This is the result:

```
result
  Bin      comparison      Obs_F    Exp_F    pValue
# 0.1   all_vs_benign  66.666667 2.352223 1.0000000
# 0.1 all_vs_damaging 500.000000 2.373318 1.0000000
# 0.2   all_vs_benign   3.333333 2.887175 0.9682472
# 0.2 all_vs_damaging   1.333333 2.827566 0.6716085
# 0.3   all_vs_benign   1.428571 3.347163 0.6869664
# 0.3 all_vs_damaging   1.666667 2.753387 0.8009820
```

Comment: Thank you very much @GGamba. Your way works fine for 3 classes, but let's suppose my data.frame has >10 classes, as is my real data.frame (I just made this example with 3 classes to illustrate the principle). I am also sure there is a more "elegant" way to do it, but it is just beyond my abilities right now. I will edit the post and add this point.

Comment: I agree, I recognize the ugliness and the un-scalability of the answer. I'll be looking again into this for sure, and/or hoping someone will come up with a solution. Probably somethin to do with `do`, `map` or even `data.table`

Comment: Check your Bin=3, as *all* is in numerator of `Obs_F` unlike first two bins: 0.1/0.07 = 1.428571 and 0.1 / 0.06 = 1.66667.