# Compute F statistics iteratively from data.frame, comparing all possible combinations of categories in column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, statistics

I am basing this question on a previous post:

[Compute F statistics iteratively from data.frame, with a specific column having the categories to be compared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304924/compute-f-statistics-iteratively-from-data-frame-with-a-specific-column-having)

Instead of comparing all unique elements of the "Class" column for every bin in the "Bin" column, I would like to compare single elements of the "Class" column along all bins in "Bin", by performing all possible combinations of bins, applying the same function of the previous post. I expect to get a data.frame that looks like this:

```
Comparison    Class      Obs_F  Exp_F  pValue
0.1_vs_0.2    benign     ...    ...    ...    
0.1_vs_0.3    benign     ...    ...    ... 
0.2_vs_0.3    benign     ...    ...    ... 
0.1_vs_0.2    damaging   ...    ...    ...  
0.1_vs_0.3    damaging   ...    ...    ... 
0.2_vs_0.3    damaging   ...    ...    ... 
0.1_vs_0.2    all        ...    ...    ... 
0.1_vs_0.3    all        ...    ...    ... 
0.2_vs_0.3    all        ...    ...    ...
```

The real data.frame has > 10 classes in the "Class" column and > 50 bins in the "Bin" column.